# In Kubernetes spark-operator , Pod Security Context is not working for spark driver and executor

Tags: apache-spark, security, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Using below command to deploy spark app (default from spark operator).

```
kubectl apply -f spark/template/spark-application.yaml
```

[used this to create spark-application](https://www.lightbend.com/blog/how-to-manage-monitor-spark-on-kubernetes-introduction-spark-submit-kubernetes-operator)

Added below values along with memory and core to run as user 1000 but sill driver and executor runs in root user.[added security context from here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator/blob/master/docs/user-guide.md)

```
spec:
  driver:
    securityContext:
      runAsUser: 1000    
  executor:
    securityContext:
      runAsUser: 1000
```

web-hook service is running in `spark-operator` namespace.

```
kubectl get service -n spark-operator    
NAME                                    TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)             AGE
spark-driver-metrics                    ClusterIP   172.20.134.198   <none>        8090/TCP            5h50m
spark-executor-metrics                  ClusterIP   172.20.91.165    <none>        8090/TCP            5h50m
spark-stream-1579262191507-driver-svc   ClusterIP   None             <none>        7078/TCP,7079/TCP   20m
spark-stream-ui-svc                     NodePort    172.20.57.54     <none>        4040:31337/TCP      20m
spark-webhook                           ClusterIP   172.20.123.24    <none>        443/TCP             5h50m
```

secrets details:

```
    kubectl get secrets -n spark-operator
    NAME                            TYPE                                  DATA   AGE
    default-token-2fgv7             kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      6h13m
    spark-token-74b8n               kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      6h13m
    spark-webhook-certs             Opaque     

                           4      6h11m
```

any help appreciated.

Comment: Hi, any errors/warns in webhook logs?

Comment: Could you post the entire yaml file you are using?

Comment: We upgraded to helm based spark operator and application install, now driver is running with user 1000. Not sure what was problem in kubectl based deployment.

Comment: @rabello spark application yaml  file or spark operator yaml file?

Comment: @anandbabu, the yaml file you are trying to run with user 1000. Helm chart solved your problem?

Comment: @rabello there may be some issue in spark-operator yaml file, after taken the default spark operator helm package, spark is running with user id 1000